# Windows app: how can a #const constant conditionally control another file?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have a lot of features that I want to each individually have the ability to conditionally compile.

I would prefer the convenience of controlling this from a single module .vb file, and not the Project > Properties > Compile > Advanced > Custom Constants list, which is a fixed size textbox and annoying to edit.

So like in 'C' I'd declare a bunch of #define macros in a .h header that all the .c files could access.

How can an analogous thing be done in `VB`?

Comment: Even in C/C++ you *don't* define *configuration* macros in files. You pass them as environment variables or command-line parameters. The same works with Visual Studio, MSBuild and the newer .NET Core tools.

Comment: This may be of use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/conditional-compilation and this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swfss70d(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Panagiotis: The subject of this question is 'conditional compilation' and not configuration.